# How to check if Selenium's find_element did find it?

Tags: perl, selenium

I'm using Perl's [Selenium::Remote::Driver](http://search.cpan.org/~gempesaw/Selenium-Remote-Driver/lib/Selenium/Remote/Driver.pm) module (or [Selenium::Chrome](http://search.cpan.org/~gempesaw/Selenium-Remote-Driver/lib/Selenium/Chrome.pm)), and in my code, I have this to find the first element which has `class="myclass"` :

```
my $elem = $selenium->find_element("myclass","class");
```

How do I know if the driver actually did find it, or if it didn't (because there was no such class in that page)?

In both cases (element found or not), I seem to be getting a [Selenium::Remote::WebElement](http://search.cpan.org/~gempesaw/Selenium-Remote-Driver/lib/Selenium/Remote/WebElement.pm) object back. But if I then `->click` it (even in an `eval` block), the whole script dies with

"An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters: myclass,class name at ...".

How can I catch this error?

Comment: Seems like the default behavior is to croak when encountering an error, which should be be caught inside of an eval block. http://search.cpan.org/~gempesaw/Selenium-Remote-Driver/lib/Selenium/Remote/Driver.pm#error_handler

Comment: @Hunter McMillen : It seems you are right. The problem was in the way I was using eval. I should probably delete this question, and refrain from posting questions late in the evening...

Comment: on the contrary, you should post the answer yourself. Your incorrect use of eval and then later solution could help someone down the road.